# How keep process running then I open new form

Tags: c#

In Microsoft Visual Studio, I have **Form1.cs**, which contains several buttons such as **btnHome**, etc. When one of them is clicked (in this case **btnHome**), it opens the child form **FormHome.cs**. When the **Start** button is clicked in **FormHome.cs**, a process starts that runs every 10 seconds and does not stop until the **stop** or **pause** button is clicked. However, if I click on the **btnStatus** or **btnSettings** button from the menu bar and return to the **btnHome** button, the process already stopped. What should I do to prevent it from stopping? I know that the data needs to be saved in a database, I'll handle that later, but how can I make the process not stop if navigating between other child forms?

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class panel : Form
    {

        private Button currentButton;
        private Random random;
        private int tempIndex;
        private Form activateForm;

        public panel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            random = new Random();
        }

        private Color SelectThemeColor()
        {
            int index = random.Next(ThemeColor.ColorList.Count);
            while (tempIndex == index)
            {
                index = random.Next(ThemeColor.ColorList.Count);
            }
            tempIndex = index;
            string color = ThemeColor.ColorList[index];
            return ColorTranslator.FromHtml(color);
        }

        private void ActivateButton(object btnSender)
        {
            if (btnSender != null)
            {
                if (currentButton != (Button)btnSender)
                {
                    DisableButton();
                    Color color = SelectThemeColor();
                    currentButton = (Button)btnSender;
                    currentButton.BackColor = color;
                    currentButton.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    currentButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                    panelTitleBar.BackColor = color;
                }
            }
        }

        private void DisableButton()
        {
            foreach (Control previousBtn in panelMenu.Controls)
            {
                if (previousBtn.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    previousBtn.BackColor = panelMenu.BackColor;
                    previousBtn.ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                    previousBtn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                }
            }
        }

        private void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, object btnSender)
        {
            ActivateButton(btnSender);
            if (activateForm != null)
            {
                activateForm.Close();
            }
            activateForm = childForm;
            childForm.TopLevel = false;
            childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panelDesktopPane.Controls.Add(childForm);
            this.panelDesktopPane.Tag = childForm;
            childForm.BringToFront();
            childForm.Show();
            lblTitle.Text = childForm.Text;
        }

        private void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenChildForm(new Forms.FormHome(), sender);
        }

        private void btnStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenChildForm(new Forms.FormStatus(), sender);
        }

        private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenChildForm(new Forms.FormSettings(), sender);
        }
    }
}
```

**FormHome.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace test.Forms
{
    public partial class FormHome : Form
    {

        private static readonly string IPv4Pattern = @"^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$";
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;

        public FormHome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            homePanel2ListView1CurlResults.View = View.Details;
            homePanel2ListView1CurlResults.Columns.Add("Time");
            homePanel2ListView1CurlResults.Columns.Add("Result");
        }

        private void homePanel1Button2Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(homePanel1TextBox1PublicIP.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a IPv4 address.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(homePanel1TextBox1PublicIP.Text, IPv4Pattern))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid IPv4 address.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            string selectedTime = homePanel1ComboBox1Time.SelectedItem?.ToString();
            if (selectedTime == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a time.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            int interval = 10000;

            _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
            {
                Interval = interval
            };
            _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
            _timer.Start();

        }

        private void homePanel1Button3Pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }

        private void homePanel1Button4Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            homePanel2ListView1CurlResults.Items.Clear();
        }

        private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = GetPublicIP();

            homePanel2ListView1CurlResults.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), result }));
        }

        private string GetPublicIP()
        {
            try
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    string response = client.DownloadString("http://ifconfig.me");
                    return response;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error retrieving IP address: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is **scope**.

This isn't working because your timer is defined on FormHome and is destroyed when you navigate out of scope.

**You could try passing your timer object as a parameter to other form when you navigate or try using an async task.**

I would try something like this.

Form1.cs

```
private bool timerIsRunning;

...
private void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     OpenChildForm(new Forms.FormHome(timerIsRunning), sender);
}
```

**FormHome.cs**

```
    bool timerIsRunning;
    public FormHome(bool _timerIsRunning)
    {
        ...
        timerisRunning = _timerIsRunning;
    }

     private void homePanel1Button2Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerIsRunning = true;
        StartTimer();
    }

     private void homePanel1Button4Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerIsRunning = false;
    }

    async void StartTimer ()
    {
        while (timerIsRunning)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            TimerTick();
        }
    }

    private void TimerTick()
    {
        // Event code here
    }
```

Comment: You have mean pass timer object to form1.cs as a global parameter?

Comment: @Boom Not as a global, rather as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Alright, after I create constructor parameter in Form1.cs what should be changed in FormHome.cs? Sorry for so many questions, I still learning.

Comment: Can you edit my code? How solution should look

Comment: @Boom try the solution I just added

Comment: Hey, I did everything by your code, but still the same.